# very poor performance react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

**I have a web application on a Reactjs, and it has very low performance even with production build**

[image]

What will help me raise my perfomance? and what could I have done so that performance was so low?

---

---

Comment: In the image you have posted there is a list of things you can do to improve scores under opportunities.

Comment: maybe someone has already used something from the library of the Reactjs to improve performance and there are some recommendations for me

Comment: Try using "compression" if you're using express server to compress your files. React waypoint is a good tool to help load things when you scroll to it

Comment: A ton of those things has nothing to do with React but rather how you serve your application to the end user. "Enable text compression" is done on the server and "Serve images in next-gen formats" means use webp for images rather then jpegs (and possibly pngs).

Comment: I just thought that this is very poor performance and maybe something I can do from my application?

Comment: May i know which tool it is to measure performance of  react application??

Comment: are you really using create-react-app? Because create-react-app (CRA) will automatically fix many of these issues, like tree-shaking, text compression. Which version of CRA are you using?

Comment: @HasanWajahat i use ```CRA version 3```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/ might be a good alternative if you care so much about performance. Also if it's just a website with no complex state management requirements just build it as a static HTML website. :)

Comment: I need ```SPA``` application, hardly ```gatsby``` will suit me

Comment: Gatsby = React + Extras (including performance optimizations).  You can think of it as a starter alternative to Create React App that also does SSR and other cool things by default.  You can build a completely dynamic SPA apps with Gatsby.  For more see: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-10-15-beyond-static-intro/

Comment: That's why I recommended it, but hey, your app your rules :)

Answer (score 0):

things you can do to improve you apps performance by seeing your snapshot.

1. set `NODE_ENV` to `production` in build
2. on your server machine use enable gzip compression
3. use can also use `cdn` to server static files (js,css,images etc)
4. use tree shaking. if you are using webpack run it in production mode.
5. use [purge unused css webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/purgecss-webpack-plugin) to remove dead css
6. use lazy loading for images
7. use code splitting to reduce your bundle sizes
8. defer scripts
9. you can also use precache