# My React Performances Audits are very bad

Tags: reactjs, performance, dom, audit

Hello I am developing an app with React, After a month of coding I started worrying about the actual performances at fist load, but not only.

I am using Chrome Dev Tool Audits to check the peformances and I get 11% and a FCP of 8.8s [Audits Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQIr0.png) seconds, but when I go to see the trace in the Performance tool I can see that after 800ms the page is already rendered as I want to [Chrome performance tool : Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M43lz.png).

Could you please explain this behaviour ? Is there something wrong with the either Audits or Performance tools, or I am misunderstanding something ? like for example the first tools actually check the "initial-load", while the second is just looking at the "normal-behaviour" once the Javascript is downloaded ?

As you can see i have a very little knowledge of this topic so any good resources (tutorials, talks) would be well appreciated

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you checking developer or production-ready version of the application? It makes sense because the production-ready version of React is more effective for rendering and optimized for being much faster than developer version

Comment: I think i am using the developer version, my fault... but i cannot try the build because i suppose i need to deploy and I cannot do that right now.
But thanks because, now,  I am hoping that the build will be a bit better in performance.

Comment: Anyway, both of the screenshot I took were from the deveveloper version, so Why they retrieve such different performances ? This was actually my question

Comment: pluus i am going to follow this steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57113024/9621179

Comment: I think there is just a problem with JS downloading. Do you use something for splitting code into the chunks?

Comment: Also check the settings of Audits before starting a test, maybe you accidentally selected throttling?